# Can you programmatically detect pluralizations of English words, and derive the singular form?

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, stemming, lemmatization

**Given some (English) word that we shall assume is a plural**, is it possible to derive the singular form? I'd like to avoid lookup/dictionary tables if possible.

Some examples:

```
Examples  -> Example    a simple 's' suffix
Glitch    -> Glitches   'es' suffix, as opposed to above
Countries -> Country    'ies' suffix.
Sheep     -> Sheep      no change: possible fallback for indeterminate values
```

Or, [this seems to be a fairly exhaustive list.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Irregular_plurals:English)

Suggestions of libraries in language `x` are fine, as long as they are open-source (ie, so that someone can examine them to determine how to do it in language `y`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by 'programmatically'.  Part of English works on easy to understand rules, and part doesn't. It has to do mainly with frequency. For a brief overview, you can read Pinker's "Words and Rules", but do yourself a favor and don't take the whole generative theory of linguistics entirely to heart. There's a lot more empiricism there than that school of thought really lends to the pursuit.

A lot of English can be statistically lemmatized.  By the way, stemming or lemmatization is the term you're looking for.  One of the most effective lemmatizers which work off of statistical rules bootstrapped with frequency-based exceptions is the [Morpha Lemmatizer](http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/research/groups/nlp/carroll/morph.html).  You can give this a shot if you have a project that requires this type of simplification of strings which represent specific terms in English.

There are even more naive approaches that accomplish much with respect to normalizing related terms. Take a look at the [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/), which is effective enough to cluster together *most* terms in English.

Comment: +1 for morpha.. i had the same problem, and morpha did a really good job at solving it

Comment: Another stemmer option is the UEA stemmer for which there are Ruby, Java, Perl, and Scala implementations.

http://github.com/ealdent/uea-stemmer/tree/master
http://www.uea.ac.uk/cmp/research/graphicsvisionspeech/speech/WordStemming
http://github.com/DRMacIver/uea-stemmer-scala/tree/master

Answer (score 5):

Going from singular to plural, English plural form is actually pretty regular compared to some other European languages I have a passing familiarity with. In German for example, working out the plural form is really complicated (eg Land -> Länder). I think there are roughly 20-30 exceptions and the rest follow a fairly simple ruleset:

- -y -> -ies (family -> families)
- -us -> -i (cactus -> cacti)
- -s -> -ses (loss -> losses)
- otherwise add -s

That being said, plural to singular form becomes that much harder because the reverse cases have ambiguities. For example:

- pies: is it py or pie?
- ski: is it singular or plural for 'skus'?
- molasses: is it singular or plural for 'molasse' or 'molass'?

So it can be done but you're going to have a much larger list of exceptions and you're going to have to store a lot of false positives (ie things that appear plural but aren't).

Comment: You could have the de-pluralizer guess which one is right, then check a dictionary to see if the word it guesses exists, but even this is going to get it wrong sometimes.

Comment: If you're using a dictionary anyway, you have access to all the plurals so there's no need for an algorithm.

Comment: In English: box -> boxes (not boxs), dish -> dishes (not dishs), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Is "axes" the plural of "ax" or of "axis"? Even a human cannot tell without context.

Comment: How about which of indexes or indices is the plural of "index"?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Inflector.net](http://andrewpeters.net/inflectornet) - my port of Rails' inflection class.

Answer (score 0):

No - English isn't a language which sticks to many rules.

I think your best bet is either:

- use a dictionary of common words and their plurals (or group them by their plural rule, eg: group words where you just add an S, words where you add ES, words where you drop a Y and add IES...)
- rethink your application

Comment: Yea, after discovering that list I linked, my hopes plummeted, but I was still curious.

Comment: English plurals are actually pretty regular. Far more so than say German or french.

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible, as nickf has already said. It would be simple for the classes of words you have described, but what about all the words that end with s naturally? My name, Marius, for example, is not plural of Mariu. Same with Bus I guess. Pluralization of words in English is a one way function (a hash function), and you usually need the rest of the sentence or paragraph for context.

Comment: For my intentended purpose, I can (relatively) safely assume that the word I am looking at is a plural, ie. in the context it wouldn't make sense elsewise.